# Search by age, location, sex and name in Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-search

Is it possible to do a search in Facebook by age, location, sex and name? I can only find the name and location filters in the web UI.

If it's not possible to do that via the web UI, how about API?

Answer (score 1):

Following link is the official link to search friends:
https://www.facebook.com/?sk=ff

There is no option for sex or age. To be more specific you can write query in search box: https://www.facebook.com/search/all/